# If I send the same data 29 times with axios post, only in the first two submissions an error occurs

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, cycle

> ```
> for (var ix=1;ix < 30;ix++){
>             axios.post(this.props.urlBase + 'Comanda', xxx, this.props.basicAuth)
>             .then((response) => {console.log("POST", response)})
>             .catch(ex => {
>                 console.log(cx,ex);
>             });
>         }
> ```

DEBUG:

> {} Error: Network Error
> at createError (c:\REACT\comande\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:1)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:11833:14)
> {config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: undefined,
> isAxiosError: true, toJSON: ƒ, …} arg0:{} arg1:Error: Network Error
> at createError (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:12339:15)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:11833:14)
> {config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: undefined,
> isAxiosError: true, toJSON: ƒ, …} config:{url:
> 'https://cloud.touristorganizer.com/wstourx/Comanda', method: 'post',
> data:
> '{"DATA":"2021-04-06","ORA":"16:24:44","TAVOLO"…":0,"PREPARATO":0,"MODIFICATO":-1,"numrig":2}',
> headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …} isAxiosError:true
> message:'Network Error'